# Comparing dates in java not working as expected

Tags: java, android, date, date-comparison

I am trying to compare 2 dates 1 is passing by paramter from the user and the other one is the current date. now for the following code its working only if the interval between the 2 dates is biiger than 1.
for example if i choose the date 10/12/2015  and the current date is 9/12/15 i got false but if the chosen date is 11/12/15 and current date is 9/12/15 i got true.

this is my code:

```
chosen_date = bundle.getString("date");
if ((new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(chosen_date).getTime() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) > System.currentTimeMillis() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) {
     datecompre = true;
     Log.d("date equ","date is bigger");
} else {
     datecompre = false;
     Log.d("date equ","date is smaller");
}
```

Comment: Just swap the true and false in the if-else statements?

Comment: but if  i will swap it when i will chose date that bigger than the current date in at least 2 days it will get into false. you cans see that i get false only when the interval is equal or less then 1 day.

Comment: Do you mean 9/12/2015 or 9/12/15

Comment: @ferrellmr "dd/MM/yyyy" - It's in the code :)

Comment: Yes - but your question has the format 9/12/15 so Im checking whether sysdate would be 15AD or 2015AD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use `Date.after()` and `Date.before()` methods.

This is an example:

```
try{

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date date1 = sdf.parse("yourFirstDate"); //or just "new Date();" if you want the current date
    Date date2 = sdf.parse("yourSecondDate"); 

    if(date1.after(date2)){
       Log.d("Date1 is after Date2");
    } else if(date1.before(date2)){
       Log.d("Date1 is before Date2");
    } else {
       Log.d("Date1 is equal Date2");
    }

}catch(ParseException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: how can i compare it with the current date?

Comment: *new Date();* will return the current date.

Comment: I think the OP wants to compare specific days (as in october 1st 1990), not dates (as in milliseconds since the epoch)

Comment: this is how should i use it with the current date?  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date date1 = sdf.parse(chosen_date);
            //Date date2 = sdf.parse(tmp.toString());
            Date date2 = new Date();

Comment: @matant Just: `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");` , `Date date1 = sdf.parse(chosen_date);`  and `Date date2 = new Date();`.